# Keep a list of users who accessed specific url in model

Tags: django

What I'm trying to do is every time a user visits a URL related to the object, a `viewed_by` field gets updated with that specific user's ID number. I've had a look at [this documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/) but I feel like it doesn't really fit exactly what I need.

I'm not sure about the implementation, which is why I'm asking this question, but this is how I'd imagine it or something like this.

```
class Documents(models.Model):
    document = models.FileField(upload_to=my_upload)
    document_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    document_viewed_by = ??? #ids of each user that viewed the document
```

Comment: If you are using postgres db you could look into arrayfields... And make an array of all ids

Answer (score 0):

You should look into a ManyToMany relationship. See docs below.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/